# Relative Permeability of Rotor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-machine

I am working on an example question from a electric machinery textbook. The question provides a simplified version of rotor and stator as shown in the picture below (please excuse me for the poor drawing here).

I was reading their algorithm for solving this question, and they gave me 2000 for the relative permeability value of the iron core or the stator, and of course 1 for the air gap.

However, they gave me 1 for the rotor. Unfortunately, the reasoning for why it is 1 is not very clear to me. I would appreciate it if someone can shine some light on this reasoning.

[image]

Comment: Probably because there is no iron in the rotor.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating-disc kilowatt-hour meters are essentially induction motors that have an aluminum disc as a rotor. The relative permeability of aluminum is 1. You could also make an induction motor with a copper rotor.